# In Laravel 5, why is Request::root() different when called during phpunit test?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, phpunit, laravel-5

I defined a test which tests the creation of a user. The controller is set to redirect back to the same page on error (using validation through a generated `App\Http\Requests\Request`). This works correctly when manually clicking in a browser, but fails during a test. Instead of being redirected to:

```
http://localhost/account/create
```

The test redirects to (missing a slash):

```
http://localhostaccount/create
```

Neither of these urls are what I have setup in the .htaccess or in the `$url` variable in config/app.php. Which is (On OSX Yosemite):

```
http://~username/laravel_projects/projectname/public
```

I finally pinpointed the issue to have something to do with how the result of `Request::root()` is generated. Making a call to this outside of a test results in the expected value defined in .htaccess and `$url`. Inside the test it results in:

```
http://localhost
```

What configuration needs to change in order to get this function to return the correct value in both contexts?

I should also mention I made the painful upgrade from Laravel 4 to the current version 5.0.27.

****** UPDATE *******

I was able to figure out an acceptable solution/workaround to this issue!

In Laravel 5, FormRequests were introduced to help move [validation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation) logic out of controllers. Once a request is mapped to the controller, if a `FormRequest` (or just `Request`) is specified, this is executed before hitting the controller action.

This `FormRequest` by default handles the response if the validation fails. It attempts to construct a redirect based on the route you posted the form data to. In my case, possibly related to an error of mine updating from Laravel 4 to 5, this default redirect was being constructed incorrectly. The [Laravel System](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php) code for handling the response looks like this:

```
 /**
 * Get the proper failed validation response for the request.
 *
 * @param  array  $errors
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson())
    {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }
    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                    ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

Notice how the returned redirect is NOT the same as calling `Redirect::route('some_route')`. You can [override](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-form-requests) this `response` function by including `use Response` in your `Request` class.

After using `Redirect::route()` to create the redirect, the logic in my tests passed with the expected results. Here is my Request code that worked:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Response;

class AccountRequest extends FormRequest {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                  'email' => 'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
                  'password' => 'required|min:6',
                  'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password'

                ];
    }

  public function response(array $errors){
    return \Redirect::route('account_create');
  }

}
```

The important part is that I called Redirect::route instead of letting the default response code execute.

Comment: The magic may lay in the [`forcedRoot`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bf87be23a152895ea6869f50aaaee25aac7870ac/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L571) functionality.  I suspect (but don't know) that In testing mode, `forcedRoot` is active, and the [rtrim in the helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bf87be23a152895ea6869f50aaaee25aac7870ac/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L596) removes the trailing slash.  Probably good to ask on irc.freenode.net/laravel

Comment: Perhaps, but I would rather avoid modifying Laravel's system code just to get something like this working. There has to be some config option that is misconfigured and causing the issue in test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Override the response function](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-form-requests) in the FormRequest validation handler to force the redirect to be constructed with Redirect::route('named_route') instead of allowing the default redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `config/app.php` file's `url` value. Default value is `http://localhost`

Doc from `config/app.php`

*This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.*

Comment: As I mentioned, I have already modified that variable to be the path where the project lives and it doesn't seem to have any affect on the test environment.

Comment: `http://~username/laravel_projects/projectname/public` What is this. You need yo set URL of your application, not folder path.
Eg: your app url is http://localhost/myapp/public, you need to set this url

Comment: I'm on a mac and the ~/Sites folder is where apache is pointing to by default. `http://~username/laravel_projects/projectname/public` is the path to where the code lives in that context. I was not using the `artisan serve` script to run the application. I understand that doing so will set the app to `localhost:8000`. I didn't think that I had to do anything like that to run the tests though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an exact answer to your question since it is **not** a configuration update that solves the problem. But I was struggling with a related problem and this seems to be the only post on the internet of someone dealing with something similar - I thought I'd put in my two cents for anyone that wants a different fix.

Please note that I'm using Laravel 4.2 at the moment, so this might have changed in Laravel 5 (although I doubt it).

You can specify the `HTTP_HOST` header when you're testing a controller using the function:

```
$response = $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content);
```

To specify the header just provided the `$server` variable as an array like so:

```
array('HTTP_HOST' => 'testing.mydomain.com');
```

When I did the above, the value produced for my `Request::root()` was `http://testing.mydomain.com`.

Again, I know this isn't a configuration update to solve you're issue, but hopefully this can help someone struggling with a semi-related issue.

Comment: This changes the domain that is used in Request::root() but it does not change the URL to include the slash between the domain and the path. Using your example, the output will be `http://testing.mydomain.comaccount/create`

Comment: it is a good idea to use $server variable, but if you changing Request::root() on the fly, there is a better way. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried changine `config/app.php` and it did not help.

it is better to use $_ENV - global variable in phpunit.

say, you want Request::root() to return 'my.site'

but you cannot touch phpunit.xml

you can simply set an env param like so

```
$_ENV['APP_URL'] = 'my.site';
```

and call `$this->refreshApplication();` in your unittest.

viola, your `request()->root()` is giving you `my.site` now.