# Laravel PHPunit - issue with adding slash

Tags: laravel-5

url() seems to be adding an extra slash, what is going on here?

```
dump(url()->previous());
if(url()->previous() == route('register')) dump('was register');
dump('--');
```

Outputs

```
"http://domain.com.au:8000//register"
"--"
```

I am expecting the previous url to match the route. However this is not the case. So where is this extra slash coming from?

[Maybe related to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483677/in-laravel-5-why-is-requestroot-different-when-called-during-phpunit-test)

This issue only presents itself while using `phpunit`

Comment: is that the HTTP referral URL? Check the previous page?

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: This issue only presents itself while using PHPUNIT

Answer (score 0):

Keep adding slashes

```
     ->seePageIs('//register');
```